# Options for menu keeps repeating after input. What did I do wrong?

Tags: python

```
#Start of program

#Main menu
    
#Greeting   
print("Hello, and welcome to Quartre AI Solution's Customer Segmentation System!")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")

def mainMenu():
    print("1. Parameter Settings")
    print("2. Customer Segmentation")
    print("3. Report Classification Summary")
    print("4. End the program")    
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#Loop for selection
#loop = 1
#choice = 0
while True:
    mainMenu()
    choice = int(input("Please enter your choice:"))
    if choice == 1:
        print("You have chosen Parameter Settings.")
        def settings(): 
            print("1. Set your parameters")
        pass
    elif choice == 2:
        print("You have chosen Customer Segmentation.")
        def segmentation():
            print("Please enter the number of customer data you would like to input")
        pass
    elif choice == 3:
        print("You have chosen Report Classification Summary.")
        def summary():
            print("Here is your report summary:")
        pass
    elif choice == 4:
        print("You have exited the program. Goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        input("Invalid selection. Please try again.")
        break
```

*Just for context: I'm making a menu for customer segmentation.*

I am getting started on Python and I tried making this simple menu with submenus but I can't get past this error. Please let me know what went wrong with my code!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

It continues as its still in while loop

Edit:Try this

```
#Start of program

#Main menu
    
#Greeting   
print("Hello, and welcome to Quartre AI Solution's Customer Segmentation System!")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")

def mainMenu():
    print("1. Parameter Settings")
    print("2. Customer Segmentation")
    print("3. Report Classification Summary")
    print("4. End the program")    
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#Loop for selection
#loop = 1
#choice = 0
while True:
    mainMenu()
    choice = int(input("Please enter your choice:"))
    if choice == 1:
        print("You have chosen Parameter Settings.")
        def settings(): 
            print("1. Set your parameters")
        break
    elif choice == 2:
        print("You have chosen Customer Segmentation.")
        def segmentation():
            print("Please enter the number of customer data you would like to input")
        break
    elif choice == 3:
        print("You have chosen Report Classification Summary.")
        def summary():
            print("Here is your report summary:")
        break
    elif choice == 4:
        print("You have exited the program. Goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        input("Invalid selection. Please try again.")
        break
```

Comment: I see, how do I fix that?

Comment: Ah! Just had to change the pass to a break! Thank you so much!

Comment: but this will break out ot the loop, do you want to do that ?